# Make only text hidden in an input form in html and css

Tags: html, css

Hay there! I made some code for a hidden input form for like a cool secret admin area, but the text still shows. I was wondering if there is any way to hide the text

```
<input class="a"> <style> .a{ border: none; } .a:focus{ border: none; outline: none;} </style>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jortfake/ygt4fcuq/7/

Comment: So you don't want to see the text the user might type into that field? You could apply `color: transparent` then, for example. But using a proper password input field would still probably make a lot more sense, than this aiming for "coolness" does to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

make the font colors match background things.

Comment: .a{
  border: none;
  color: #00000000;
}

Comment: Thank you! I added color: white so its blends to the background!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `visibility: hidden;` on your `<h2>`

```css
.a{
  border: none;
}
.a:focus{
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

h2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input value="" class="a">
<h2>
The input form is right above me. 
</h2>
```

To hide the text inside the input element you can use:

```
.a {
   color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I put it there so everyone looking at my fiddle wouldn't have trouble finding it

Comment: @TheYoungCoder you asked for a way to hide the text, this hides the text. If you want something else please update your question.